Can I manage multiple bases in alembic across git repos?
We currently have a monolithic database that we manage with SQLAlchemy and alembic on which we have a number of applications that read and write, each located in a separate git repo. At present, our DB table definitions and ORMs are managed in a single central library shared by all these applications.
We'd like to move to a more distributed system, where ORM definitions are distributed more across the applications if it only concerns data of relevance for their respective scope. However, we'd like to keep some foreign key constraints into other tables within the same DB even if the according table definitions are managed in the shared library. As far as I understand, alembic in principle supports some degree of database scope partitioning with branches and bases, but it is not evident to me whether this concept can be extended beyond the boundaries of a single (git) repository.
Accordingly, can I manage multiple bases/branches that manage parts of a single DB schema across multiple repos, or do all alembic migration files etc. have to be locally relative to wherever the alembic.ini file resides?
Should this scenario not be achievable with alembic but possibly some other tool I'd also appreciate according pointers.
